# Eclipse Plugin Development install dependencies if not installed yet

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

Hey guys,
I'm developing a plugin for eclipse and I need some dependencies, e.g. org.eclipse.graphiti.
When I export my plugin and when I build my update site, everthing works fine, until i try to install my plugin, because then the install wizard says I don't have graphiti installed. How can I tell my wizard to ask if you want to install the needed plugin automatically?

Thanks for any help and ideas.

Comment: Some pointers until someone with more knowledge chimes in: P2 update site can refer to other update sites. So I would try to make my update site to point to another site which contains 'graphiti'. Also make sure you check "Contact other update sites" or similar checkbox when installing new plugins.

Comment: the supposed checkbox doesn't help, but i will focus on p2, thx.

Answer (score 0):

During install select the 'Contact all available update sites' checkbox in the lower part of the feature selection dialog. This allows searching all existing update sites. This might help, or if not, then add the Graphiti update site your feature.xml.